# How To Extract Distinct ID's Present In One Table But Not Another

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, one with the sales entries (multiple of the same salesman id number), and another that is a master file of sales people (only one salesman id per each salesman).

How can I write a query (via BigQuery) which identifies the distinct salesman_ids which are present in the  sales_table, but are NOT present in the salesman_ids table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below option is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT e.salesman_id
FROM sales_entries e
LEFT JOIN sales_people p
USING(salesman_id)
WHERE p.salesman_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `not exists`:

```
select s.salesman_id
from sales_table s
where not exists (select 1
                  from salesman_ids sm
                  where sm.salesman_id = s.salesman_id
                 );
```